# Best way to fix tile

Tags: masonry, mortar, tiling, cement

One of our old tiles suddenly feel off, the others seem ok.

What's the best to fix back.  I don't think I'll be able to get a new tile to match, and I don't think I can chisel the old mortar off without it breaking.

See pics:
[enter link description here](https://photos.app.goo.gl/GRpzSyeq17BBbYjK7)

[enter link description here](https://photos.app.goo.gl/zB8BNzrVRRyNhdMR9)

Answer (score 2):

As long as the old mortar on the wall isn't crumbling you should be able to replace it without too much difficulty. Use a wire brush and get as much of the old mortar off the wall and the tile as you can, especially anything loose. For only one or two tiles I just use a good construction adhesive such as Liquid Nails for marble and tile. Use some spacers to keep your seams even, Support the tile in place while it dries. If the tile isn't too heavy you can use duct tape to hold it. Then just grout the seams. Good luck.

Comment: Loctite Premium adhesive works great for stuff like this.+